# Why am I unable to reproduce the GitHub Email Incident issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github

GitHub reported an issue in Rails 3.2.13 scoping behavior that caused an email incident:
https://github.com/blog/1440-today-s-email-incident

I put together a small sample app with fixtures/tests based on the blog post. Using Appraisal, it's being tested against Rails 3.2.12, 3.2.13, 3.2.14, and 4.0.0.

https://github.com/nathany/incident

I would expect a test failure on 3.2.13, but I'm not seeing it. Please advise.

Comment: You need to trigger a scope merge. The easiest way to do this is via a default_scope

Comment: Okay, but there is no default scope or merge in GitHub's blog post. I've also experimented with queries on our own app where the default scope is just an order(), so far no problems. 

The concern is our app had tonnes of problems in production with 3.2.13, but I still don't know why or if 3.2.14 will be a smoother upgrade.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about very specific conditions that are not likely to help other users: Too localized.